# matplotlib/cartopy - quiver key cut off

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

Note: moved to a smaller example at [matplotlib quiver key label getting cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717968/matplotlib-quiver-key-label-getting-cut)

Trying to work how to keep the quiver key in the figure as it is currently getting cut off. I'm using cartopy and hoping to put the quiver key outside of the map. Here's how it currently looks. I've highlighted where the quiver key is showing up but the text to the east is automatically cut-off. Code given below which is taken from the [docs](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/regridding_arrows.html).

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import cartopy.crs as ccrs


def sample_data(shape=(20, 30)):
    crs = ccrs.NorthPolarStereo()
    scale = 1e7
    x = np.linspace(-scale, scale, shape[1])
    y = np.linspace(-scale, scale, shape[0])

    x2d, y2d = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    u = 10 * np.cos(2 * x2d / scale + 3 * y2d / scale)
    v = 20 * np.cos(6 * x2d / scale)

    return x, y, u, v, crs


x, y, u, v, vector_crs = sample_data(shape=(50, 50))
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(13, 8))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines('50m')
ax.set_extent([-45, 55, 20, 80], ccrs.PlateCarree())
q = ax.quiver(x, y, u, v, transform=vector_crs, regrid_shape=20)
qk = plt.quiverkey(q, 1, 0.9, 30,
                   'velocity (30 m s$^{-1}$)', labelpos='E', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with this, but the position of x is important because changing the position of x in `put.quiverkey()` causes the string to be displayed. And `labelpos='W'` will show it on the west side.

```
qk = plt.quiverkey(q, 0.9, 0.92, 30,
                   'velocity (30 m s$^{-1}$)',
                   labelpos='W',
                   transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                   color='r')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. the labelpos is a nice arg but i'm still looking on putting it outside of the map.

Comment: My understanding is that unless you make the graph drawing area smaller, it won't be displayed if it overhangs the graph area.