# matplotlib quiver key label getting cut

Tags: python, matplotlib

When copying the example in the docs the label associated with the quiver key is not showing up. Any thoughts?

Edit: Thanks all for your responses. @X helped me realize the difference comes from using `plot.show()` and viewing the plot after saving `plt.savefig('plot')`.

https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/quiver_demo.html#advanced-quiver-and-quiverkey-functions

Expected:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, .2), np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, .2))
U = np.cos(X)
V = np.sin(Y)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_title('Arrows scale with plot width, not view')
Q = ax1.quiver(X, Y, U, V, units='width')
qk = ax1.quiverkey(Q, 0.9, 0.9, 2, r'$2 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E',
                   coordinates='figure')
```

Actual:

[image]

Edit: tight_layout seems to 'squish' my key.

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_title('Arrows scale with plot width, not view')
Q = ax1.quiver(X, Y, U, V, units='width')
qk = ax1.quiverkey(Q, 0.9, 0.9, 2, r'$2 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E',
                   coordinates='figure')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit: Another example: it seems trying the simple quiver example in the docs cuts off the key for me.

https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/quiver_simple_demo.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(-10, 10, 1)
Y = np.arange(-10, 10, 1)
U, V = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
q = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V)
ax.quiverkey(q, X=0.3, Y=1.1, U=10,
             label='Quiver key, length = 10', labelpos='E')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit 2: Using `coordinates='axes'` does help a bit to know where the key is going but it still cuts off the label for me.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, .2), np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, .2))
U = np.cos(X)
V = np.sin(Y)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_title('Arrows scale with plot width, not view')
Q = ax1.quiver(X, Y, U, V, units='width')
qk = ax1.quiverkey(Q, 1.0, 1.02, 2, r'$2 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E',
                   coordinates='axes')
```

[image]

OS: Windows

Python: 3.8.6

Matplotlib-base: 3.3.2

Matplotlib settings: No changes to rcparams (see below).

Environment: Jupyter lab with a postBuild script but I don't think is related.

```
plt.rcParams
RcParams({'_internal.classic_mode': False,
          'agg.path.chunksize': 0,
          'animation.avconv_args': [],
          'animation.avconv_path': 'avconv',
          'animation.bitrate': -1,
          'animation.codec': 'h264',
          'animation.convert_args': [],
          'animation.convert_path': 'convert',
          'animation.embed_limit': 20.0,
          'animation.ffmpeg_args': [],
          'animation.ffmpeg_path': 'ffmpeg',
          'animation.frame_format': 'png',
          'animation.html': 'none',
          'animation.html_args': [],
          'animation.writer': 'ffmpeg',
          'axes.autolimit_mode': 'data',
          'axes.axisbelow': 'line',
          'axes.edgecolor': 'black',
          'axes.facecolor': 'white',
          'axes.formatter.limits': [-5, 6],
          'axes.formatter.min_exponent': 0,
          'axes.formatter.offset_threshold': 4,
          'axes.formatter.use_locale': False,
          'axes.formatter.use_mathtext': False,
          'axes.formatter.useoffset': True,
          'axes.grid': False,
          'axes.grid.axis': 'both',
          'axes.grid.which': 'major',
          'axes.labelcolor': 'black',
          'axes.labelpad': 4.0,
          'axes.labelsize': 'medium',
          'axes.labelweight': 'normal',
          'axes.linewidth': 0.8,
          'axes.prop_cycle': cycler('color', ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#d62728', '#9467bd', '#8c564b', '#e377c2', '#7f7f7f', '#bcbd22', '#17becf']),
          'axes.spines.bottom': True,
          'axes.spines.left': True,
          'axes.spines.right': True,
          'axes.spines.top': True,
          'axes.titlecolor': 'auto',
          'axes.titlelocation': 'center',
          'axes.titlepad': 6.0,
          'axes.titlesize': 'large',
          'axes.titleweight': 'normal',
          'axes.titley': None,
          'axes.unicode_minus': True,
          'axes.xmargin': 0.05,
          'axes.ymargin': 0.05,
          'axes3d.grid': True,
          'backend': 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline',
          'backend_fallback': True,
          'boxplot.bootstrap': None,
          'boxplot.boxprops.color': 'black',
          'boxplot.boxprops.linestyle': '-',
          'boxplot.boxprops.linewidth': 1.0,
          'boxplot.capprops.color': 'black',
          'boxplot.capprops.linestyle': '-',
          'boxplot.capprops.linewidth': 1.0,
          'boxplot.flierprops.color': 'black',
          'boxplot.flierprops.linestyle': 'none',
          'boxplot.flierprops.linewidth': 1.0,
          'boxplot.flierprops.marker': 'o',
          'boxplot.flierprops.markeredgecolor': 'black',
          'boxplot.flierprops.markeredgewidth': 1.0,
          'boxplot.flierprops.markerfacecolor': 'none',
          'boxplot.flierprops.markersize': 6.0,
          'boxplot.meanline': False,
          'boxplot.meanprops.color': 'C2',
          'boxplot.meanprops.linestyle': '--',
          'boxplot.meanprops.linewidth': 1.0,
          'boxplot.meanprops.marker': '^',
          'boxplot.meanprops.markeredgecolor': 'C2',
          'boxplot.meanprops.markerfacecolor': 'C2',
          'boxplot.meanprops.markersize': 6.0,
          'boxplot.medianprops.color': 'C1',
          'boxplot.medianprops.linestyle': '-',
          'boxplot.medianprops.linewidth': 1.0,
          'boxplot.notch': False,
          'boxplot.patchartist': False,
          'boxplot.showbox': True,
          'boxplot.showcaps': True,
          'boxplot.showfliers': True,
          'boxplot.showmeans': False,
          'boxplot.vertical': True,
          'boxplot.whiskerprops.color': 'black',
          'boxplot.whiskerprops.linestyle': '-',
          'boxplot.whiskerprops.linewidth': 1.0,
          'boxplot.whiskers': 1.5,
          'contour.corner_mask': True,
          'contour.linewidth': None,
          'contour.negative_linestyle': 'dashed',
          'date.autoformatter.day': '%Y-%m-%d',
          'date.autoformatter.hour': '%m-%d %H',
          'date.autoformatter.microsecond': '%M:%S.%f',
          'date.autoformatter.minute': '%d %H:%M',
          'date.autoformatter.month': '%Y-%m',
          'date.autoformatter.second': '%H:%M:%S',
          'date.autoformatter.year': '%Y',
          'date.epoch': '1970-01-01T00:00:00',
          'docstring.hardcopy': False,
          'errorbar.capsize': 0.0,
          'figure.autolayout': False,
          'figure.constrained_layout.h_pad': 0.04167,
          'figure.constrained_layout.hspace': 0.02,
          'figure.constrained_layout.use': False,
          'figure.constrained_layout.w_pad': 0.04167,
          'figure.constrained_layout.wspace': 0.02,
          'figure.dpi': 72.0,
          'figure.edgecolor': (1, 1, 1, 0),
          'figure.facecolor': (1, 1, 1, 0),
          'figure.figsize': [6.0, 4.0],
          'figure.frameon': True,
          'figure.max_open_warning': 20,
          'figure.raise_window': True,
          'figure.subplot.bottom': 0.125,
          'figure.subplot.hspace': 0.2,
          'figure.subplot.left': 0.125,
          'figure.subplot.right': 0.9,
          'figure.subplot.top': 0.88,
          'figure.subplot.wspace': 0.2,
          'figure.titlesize': 'large',
          'figure.titleweight': 'normal',
          'font.cursive': ['Apple Chancery',
                           'Textile',
                           'Zapf Chancery',
                           'Sand',
                           'Script MT',
                           'Felipa',
                           'cursive'],
          'font.family': ['sans-serif'],
          'font.fantasy': ['Comic Neue',
                           'Comic Sans MS',
                           'Chicago',
                           'Charcoal',
                           'ImpactWestern',
                           'Humor Sans',
                           'xkcd',
                           'fantasy'],
          'font.monospace': ['DejaVu Sans Mono',
                             'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono',
                             'Computer Modern Typewriter',
                             'Andale Mono',
                             'Nimbus Mono L',
                             'Courier New',
                             'Courier',
                             'Fixed',
                             'Terminal',
                             'monospace'],
          'font.sans-serif': ['DejaVu Sans',
                              'Bitstream Vera Sans',
                              'Computer Modern Sans Serif',
                              'Lucida Grande',
                              'Verdana',
                              'Geneva',
                              'Lucid',
                              'Arial',
                              'Helvetica',
                              'Avant Garde',
                              'sans-serif'],
          'font.serif': ['DejaVu Serif',
                         'Bitstream Vera Serif',
                         'Computer Modern Roman',
                         'New Century Schoolbook',
                         'Century Schoolbook L',
                         'Utopia',
                         'ITC Bookman',
                         'Bookman',
                         'Nimbus Roman No9 L',
                         'Times New Roman',
                         'Times',
                         'Palatino',
                         'Charter',
                         'serif'],
          'font.size': 10.0,
          'font.stretch': 'normal',
          'font.style': 'normal',
          'font.variant': 'normal',
          'font.weight': 'normal',
          'grid.alpha': 1.0,
          'grid.color': '#b0b0b0',
          'grid.linestyle': '-',
          'grid.linewidth': 0.8,
          'hatch.color': 'black',
          'hatch.linewidth': 1.0,
          'hist.bins': 10,
          'image.aspect': 'equal',
          'image.cmap': 'viridis',
          'image.composite_image': True,
          'image.interpolation': 'antialiased',
          'image.lut': 256,
          'image.origin': 'upper',
          'image.resample': True,
          'interactive': True,
          'keymap.all_axes': ['a'],
          'keymap.back': ['left', 'c', 'backspace', 'MouseButton.BACK'],
          'keymap.copy': ['ctrl+c', 'cmd+c'],
          'keymap.forward': ['right', 'v', 'MouseButton.FORWARD'],
          'keymap.fullscreen': ['f', 'ctrl+f'],
          'keymap.grid': ['g'],
          'keymap.grid_minor': ['G'],
          'keymap.help': ['f1'],
          'keymap.home': ['h', 'r', 'home'],
          'keymap.pan': ['p'],
          'keymap.quit': ['ctrl+w', 'cmd+w', 'q'],
          'keymap.quit_all': [],
          'keymap.save': ['s', 'ctrl+s'],
          'keymap.xscale': ['k', 'L'],
          'keymap.yscale': ['l'],
          'keymap.zoom': ['o'],
          'legend.borderaxespad': 0.5,
          'legend.borderpad': 0.4,
          'legend.columnspacing': 2.0,
          'legend.edgecolor': '0.8',
          'legend.facecolor': 'inherit',
          'legend.fancybox': True,
          'legend.fontsize': 'medium',
          'legend.framealpha': 0.8,
          'legend.frameon': True,
          'legend.handleheight': 0.7,
          'legend.handlelength': 2.0,
          'legend.handletextpad': 0.8,
          'legend.labelspacing': 0.5,
          'legend.loc': 'best',
          'legend.markerscale': 1.0,
          'legend.numpoints': 1,
          'legend.scatterpoints': 1,
          'legend.shadow': False,
          'legend.title_fontsize': None,
          'lines.antialiased': True,
          'lines.color': 'C0',
          'lines.dash_capstyle': 'butt',
          'lines.dash_joinstyle': 'round',
          'lines.dashdot_pattern': [6.4, 1.6, 1.0, 1.6],
          'lines.dashed_pattern': [3.7, 1.6],
          'lines.dotted_pattern': [1.0, 1.65],
          'lines.linestyle': '-',
          'lines.linewidth': 1.5,
          'lines.marker': 'None',
          'lines.markeredgecolor': 'auto',
          'lines.markeredgewidth': 1.0,
          'lines.markerfacecolor': 'auto',
          'lines.markersize': 6.0,
          'lines.scale_dashes': True,
          'lines.solid_capstyle': 'projecting',
          'lines.solid_joinstyle': 'round',
          'markers.fillstyle': 'full',
          'mathtext.bf': 'sans:bold',
          'mathtext.cal': 'cursive',
          'mathtext.default': 'it',
          'mathtext.fallback': 'cm',
          'mathtext.fallback_to_cm': None,
          'mathtext.fontset': 'dejavusans',
          'mathtext.it': 'sans:italic',
          'mathtext.rm': 'sans',
          'mathtext.sf': 'sans',
          'mathtext.tt': 'monospace',
          'mpl_toolkits.legacy_colorbar': True,
          'patch.antialiased': True,
          'patch.edgecolor': 'black',
          'patch.facecolor': 'C0',
          'patch.force_edgecolor': False,
          'patch.linewidth': 1.0,
          'path.effects': [],
          'path.simplify': True,
          'path.simplify_threshold': 0.111111111111,
          'path.sketch': None,
          'path.snap': True,
          'pcolor.shading': 'flat',
          'pdf.compression': 6,
          'pdf.fonttype': 3,
          'pdf.inheritcolor': False,
          'pdf.use14corefonts': False,
          'pgf.preamble': '',
          'pgf.rcfonts': True,
          'pgf.texsystem': 'xelatex',
          'polaraxes.grid': True,
          'ps.distiller.res': 6000,
          'ps.fonttype': 3,
          'ps.papersize': 'letter',
          'ps.useafm': False,
          'ps.usedistiller': None,
          'savefig.bbox': None,
          'savefig.directory': '~',
          'savefig.dpi': 'figure',
          'savefig.edgecolor': 'auto',
          'savefig.facecolor': 'auto',
          'savefig.format': 'png',
          'savefig.jpeg_quality': 95,
          'savefig.orientation': 'portrait',
          'savefig.pad_inches': 0.1,
          'savefig.transparent': False,
          'scatter.edgecolors': 'face',
          'scatter.marker': 'o',
          'svg.fonttype': 'path',
          'svg.hashsalt': None,
          'svg.image_inline': True,
          'text.antialiased': True,
          'text.color': 'black',
          'text.hinting': 'force_autohint',
          'text.hinting_factor': 8,
          'text.kerning_factor': 0,
          'text.latex.preamble': '',
          'text.latex.preview': False,
          'text.usetex': False,
          'timezone': 'UTC',
          'tk.window_focus': False,
          'toolbar': 'toolbar2',
          'webagg.address': '127.0.0.1',
          'webagg.open_in_browser': True,
          'webagg.port': 8988,
          'webagg.port_retries': 50,
          'xaxis.labellocation': 'center',
          'xtick.alignment': 'center',
          'xtick.bottom': True,
          'xtick.color': 'black',
          'xtick.direction': 'out',
          'xtick.labelbottom': True,
          'xtick.labelsize': 'medium',
          'xtick.labeltop': False,
          'xtick.major.bottom': True,
          'xtick.major.pad': 3.5,
          'xtick.major.size': 3.5,
          'xtick.major.top': True,
          'xtick.major.width': 0.8,
          'xtick.minor.bottom': True,
          'xtick.minor.pad': 3.4,
          'xtick.minor.size': 2.0,
          'xtick.minor.top': True,
          'xtick.minor.visible': False,
          'xtick.minor.width': 0.6,
          'xtick.top': False,
          'yaxis.labellocation': 'center',
          'ytick.alignment': 'center_baseline',
          'ytick.color': 'black',
          'ytick.direction': 'out',
          'ytick.labelleft': True,
          'ytick.labelright': False,
          'ytick.labelsize': 'medium',
          'ytick.left': True,
          'ytick.major.left': True,
          'ytick.major.pad': 3.5,
          'ytick.major.right': True,
          'ytick.major.size': 3.5,
          'ytick.major.width': 0.8,
          'ytick.minor.left': True,
          'ytick.minor.pad': 3.4,
          'ytick.minor.right': True,
          'ytick.minor.size': 2.0,
          'ytick.minor.visible': False,
          'ytick.minor.width': 0.6,
          'ytick.right': False})
```

Comment: Identical settings here except for Jupyter. Although I can reproduce the `tight.layout()` problem, I cannot reproduce the initial problem. Backend differences? `rcparams` changed? Jupyter?

Comment: @Mr.T is your default figure size [6.0, 4.0] as well?

Comment: My standard is [6.4, 4.8] but setting it to [6.0, 4.0] (or any other, even extreme, figure size) does not reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that somehow your backend is changing the figure size on you and that moves the quiver key.  Why do you want it in figure co-ordinates?  Suggest you position it relative to the axes:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, .2), np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, .2))
U = np.cos(X)
V = np.sin(Y)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_title('Arrows scale with plot width, not view')
Q = ax1.quiver(X, Y, U, V, units='width')
qk = ax1.quiverkey(Q, 1.0, 1.02, 2, r'$2 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E',
                   coordinates='axes')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it's still cutting off the label for me.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “cutting off”. If you place the key outside the figure it will be “cut off” unless you use bbox_inches=tight when saving

Comment: Please reproduce your error in a PDF or png file.  Then we can know it is not your backend.  If you can only reproduce in your backend, then that is something to report to them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between using a coordinate reference as an axis and a figure. The background color of the figure is pink and the background color of the axis is yellow.

```
qk = ax1.quiverkey(Q, 0.85, 0.9, 2, r'$2 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E', coordinates='figure')
```

[image]

```
qk = ax1.quiverkey(Q, 0.85, 0.9, 2, r'$2 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E', coordinates='axes')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, tight_layout!   (it's a bit of a quick/easy fix, vs. fiddling forever with various margin attributes)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, .2), np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, .2))
U = np.cos(X)
V = np.sin(Y)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_title('Arrows scale with plot width, not view')
Q = ax1.quiver(X, Y, U, V, units='width')
qk = ax1.quiverkey(Q, 0.92, .95, 2, r'$2 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E',
                   coordinates='figure')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Mind sharing your mpl version etc.?

Comment: Matplotlib: 3.2.1
Numpy: 1.18.5
Python: 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to modify the coordinates of the key manually for different `figsize`. For the default `(6,4)`:

```
qk = ax1.quiverkey(Q, 0.93, 0.93, 2, r'$2 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E',
                   coordinates='figure')
plt.tight_layout()
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That does seem to help with tight_layout. Were you able to reproduce my issue 
 without tight_layout?

Comment: @RayBell yes, I was. Without `tight_layout` using `0.85, 0.9` helps.

Answer (score 0):

coordinates = [ 'axes' | 'figure' | 'data' | 'inches' ]
Coordinate system and units for X, Y:

- 'axes' and 'figure' are normalized coordinate systems with 0,0 in the lower left and 1,1 in the upper right
- 'data' are the axes data coordinates (used for the locations of the vectors in the quiver plot itself)
- 'inches' is position in the figure in inches, with 0,0 at the lower left corner.